# Attach photos to an e-mail, but not inline with the body

Tags: images, thunderbird, attachments

When I send emails with a photo through Thunderbird, the photo appears both as an attachment as well as in the body of the email.

I do not want the photo to appear in the body.

Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 3):

Just to be sure, send the e-mail as plain text and the photo as an attachment.

Answer (score 3):

From [mozillazine.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plain_text_e-mail_%28Thunderbird%29):

"View -> Display Attachments Inline. Checking it lets you view embedded images inline, rather than as attachments"

This might do the trick.